# On sixth powers $a^6+b^{12}+c^{12} = d^6+e^{12}+f^{12}$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-mathematics

To recall, there are infinitely many **primitive** solutions to,
$$a^4+b^8+c^8 = d^4+e^8+f^8$$
such as,
$$14805^4 + 86^8 + 149^8  = 18939^4 + 35^8 + 142^8$$

discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4578666/4781). This almost violates the *Lander-Parkin conjecture* (which states that for ESLP with $k>3$, at least $k$ terms are needed).

---

**I. Sixth Powers**

Going higher, it turns out there are infinitely many primitive solutions to,
$$x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^{\color{blue}{12}} = y_1^6+y_2^6+y_3^{\color{blue}{12}}$$

small ones of which are,

$$\; 179^6 + 275^6\, + 6^{\color{blue}{12}} = 276^6 + 65^6 + 13^{\color{blue}{12}}$$
$$111^6 + 230 ^6 + 11^{\color{blue}{12}} = 26^6 + 13^{\color{blue}{12}} + 15^{\color{blue}{12}}$$

To find infinitely more of the first kind, we use the $6$th-power parameterization with the smallest known degree, the *Brudno-Delorme Identity*,

\begin{align}
a &= -n^4 - n^3 - 5n^2 + 8n + 8\\
b &= (n^3 + 7n - 2)(n + 2)\\ 
c &= 9n^2 + 6n + 12\\
d &= -n^4 + n^2 + 14n + 4\\
e &= -4n^3 - 5n^2 - 8n + 8\\
f &= (n^2 - n + 3)(n + 2)^2
\end{align}

which obeys at least three relations,

$$a^6+b^6+c^6 = d^6+e^6+f^6$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2+e^2+f^2$$
$$3a+b+c = 3d+e+f$$

To make two of its terms as squares, we simply solve,

\begin{align}
9n^2 + 6n + 12 &= \square_1\\[4pt]
n^2 - n + 3 &= \square_2\end{align}

starting with initial rational point $n = -13/24.$ Converting this into an *elliptic curve*, one can then find infinitely more points.

---

**II. Question**

Since,

$$a^6 + b^6 + c^{\color{blue}{12}} = d^6 + e^{\color{blue}{12}} + f^{\color{blue}{12}}$$

has at least one non-trivial solution given above, can we in fact also solve,

$$a^6 + b^{\color{blue}{12}} + c^{\color{blue}{12}} = d^6 + e^{\color{blue}{12}} + f^{\color{blue}{12}}$$

where $(a,b,c)\neq(d,e,f)$?